# Is there any difference between Python list slicing [-1:] and [-1]?

Tags: python, list

I have read a snippet of code like this:

```
s = self.buffer_file.readline()
if s[-1:] == "\n":
    return s
```

And if I do this:

```
s = 'abc'
In [78]: id(s[-1:]), id(s[-1])
Out[78]: (140419827715248, 140419827715248)

In [79]: id(s[-1:]) is id(s[-1])
Out[79]: False

In [80]: id(s[-1:]) == id(s[-1])
Out[80]: True
```

It doesn't make sense to me, the ID numbers are same, but the IDs are different. So they are different for some reason.

Comment: Comparing the identity of `id()` results is meaningless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is that the result of slicing a list is a list

```
x = [1, 2, 3]

print(x[-1])  # --> 3
print(x[-1:]) # --> [3]
```

The second case just happens to be a list of one element, but it's still a list.

Note however that Python doesn't have a `char` type distinct from the `str` type and this means that both element access and slicing on `str` objects return another `str` object:

```
print("abcd"[-1])  # --> "d"
print("abcd"[-1:]) # --> "d"
```

The only advantage of using for example `s[-1:]` or `s[:1]` with a string instead of `s[-1]` and `s[0]` is that the slice expressions will not raise a runtime error when acting on an empty string (something that element access does)... this may allow code simplification:

```
if len(s) > 0 and s[0] == '*': ...
if s[:1] == '*': ...
```

Comment: @liaozd: see edit about slicing strings. Python doesn't have a `char` type and therefore both element access and slicing of a string returns a string.

Answer (score 7):

The key practical benefit to `s[-1:]` rather than `s[-1]` is that the former will produce an empty iterable rather than stopping with a traceback.

```
>>> 'hi'[-1:]
'i'
>>> 'hi'[-1]
'i'
>>> ''[-1:]
''
>>> ''[-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

This allows `if s[-1:] == "\n":` to handle an empty line `s` without preceding it with `if s:` by simply evaluating to `False` instead of generating an error that would need to be handled with a `try..except` structure.

Answer (score 5):

The `id(s[-1:]) is id(s[-1])` means the id themselves (integers) are reference equal. Assuming CPython 2.

This question may be implementation specified.

Be aware of the small integer pool. http://davejingtian.org/2014/12/11/python-internals-integer-object-pool-pyintobject/.

This may help:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep 23 2015, 04:34:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)] on darwin

>>> s = 'abc'
>>> s[-1:]
'c'
>>> s[-1]
'c'
>>> s[-1:]
'c'
>>> a = s[-1:]
>>> b = s[-1]
>>> id(a)
4531751912
>>> id(b)
4531751912
>>> a is b
True
>>> id(a) is id(b)
False
```

The objects `a` and `b` are the same object, but their `id` are two `ints` that are not "reference equal".

More on integers:

```
>>> 5 is 100
False
>>> 5 is 5
True
>>> 10000 is 10000
True
>>> 1000000000 is 1000000000
True
>>> a = 10000000
>>> a is 10000000
False
>>> a, b = 100000000, 100000000
>>> a is b
True
>>> a is 100000000
False
>>> id(100000000)
140715808080880
>>> id(a)
140715808080664
>>> id(b)
140715808080664
>>> id(100000000)
140715808080640
>>>
```

Further reading:
PyPy implementation details about this: http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html#object-identity-of-primitive-values-is-and-id

Comment: If I do `a, b = 1, 1`, then `a is b` returns `True`!

Comment: Strings are kind of special -- their "elements" are also strings. That's why you get the same `id` for `a` and `b`. You wouldn't get that for a list, because `a` would be a (one-element) list, and `b` would be a value from the list (as @6502 says in their answer).

Comment: @oliverpool It seems the same numbers in one line shares the same ids.

Comment: @jiegec if I split it on multiple lines, it still holds `a = 1`, `b = 2`, `c = 1` makes `a is c` returns `True`

Comment: @oliverpool Don't forget python has a pool for small numbers. You must test big numbers.

Comment: @jiegec that's it: Thanks, I actually didn't know about it! And it's probably the actual answer to the question!!!